# php external site login then go to another page

Tags: php, http, curl, post, http-post

I need to login to another site with php then get the contents from another page of this site, because after login it goes to the home page I need the customers page.
I tried with file_get_contents and curl but the latter is known to be better here the code with php curl:

```
$username='username';
$password='password';
$cookie="/home/cookie.txt"; 

$url = 'http://the-site.com/';
$postdata = "?&username=$username&password=$password&op=login&rUrl=? 
op=customers";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 


$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  

curl_close($ch);
```

*op* and *rUrl* are the names of hidden input tag. 
If I put the *$url+$postdata* in the address bar of the browser it goes to the desired page, but through code it doesn't work as expected, it remains to the login page without entering in.

Comment: You probably need to remove `?&` from the start of your `$postdata` string.

Comment: Done but I got blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

it works because:

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).

After log in it will be redirected to the page specified in the url.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$postdata` appears to be invalid - it shouldn't have that leading `?&`. Also `op` appears twice, second time as `op=customers` after another `?`:

`$postdata = "?&username=$username&password=$password&op=login&rUrl=? 
op=customers";`

[`http_build_query`](https://php.net/http_build_query) is recommended here to ensure you generate a precise URL-encoded query string, like so:

```
$postdata = [
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'op' => 'login',
    'rUrl' => 'customers',
];

echo '$postdata: ' . http_build_query($postdata);
exit;
```

Comment: I got blank page.

Comment: @blob you need to do some further debugging then. What should the values for `op` and `rUrl` be? Should `op` be `login` or `customers`? Try sorting these values out first. Then try inspecting the `curl_exec` response with this code after it is executed: `echo '<pre>$result' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: op is login and rUrl should be the url to redirect after login, which is ?op=customers. Typing this request on a browser works, it log in and goes to the customers page.

Comment: OK, well perhaps try to change the `rUrl` parameter in the array to `?op=customers` before the array is passed to `http_build_query` (wherein it will be properly url-encoded this time!), depending on the way the third-party system works... this *might* solve your issue

Comment: Unfortunately I always get blank page. i don't know why, in the browser it works!

Comment: @blob ok - debugging time then. What do you get from this? `echo 'var_dump result: '; echo '<pre>' . var_dump($result) . '</pre>';`

Comment: I get var_dump result: string(0) "", it seems that it doesn't get the page.
OK I get the page CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION should be set to 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172090/discussion-between-blob-and-ajmedway).